# Do you have to list ingredients in a food takeout business in New York State?

Tags: new-york-state, health, food-processing

My wife just opened a food takeout business in New York State. 
She sells coffee, sandwiches, salads, pastas, danishes, and the like. 
Some of the products, for example some salads, pastas, sandwiches and desserts are pre-packaged for convenience and efficiency, but it's not a factory.

The local health department is telling us we have to list the ingredients on the label.  How is the business I describe different from a restaurant? I've been to plenty of restaurants that offer takeout and nobody lists ingredients.

Comment: Is the majority of her sales from pre-packaged goods, or is it mostly custom made on demand?  Does she have any seating?

Comment: I'd say 50% on demand, 50% pre-packaged. But it's fresh pre-packaged, like done in the morning for the customers that will come in during the day. There is no seating (it's a small place).